# JQuery infinite loop on tablerow click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm having trouble with an infinite loop.. at least I think so.

I'm generating a table via Ajax. A table row contains a button with a thumbnail and some text.
When I click the `TableRow` I want the button in the `TableRow` to be clicked. If I don't use .one("click") I'm getting an infinite loop.

I wouldn't like to use. one because you can't click another `TableRow`when u revisit the site via a "go back" button.

HTML:

```
<form method = 'post' action = 'view.cfm'>
    <table class = 'result_table'>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>Thumbnail</th>
            <th>Dateityp</th>
            <th>Titel</th>
            <th>Dateiname</th>
            <th>Dateigröße</th>
        </tr>
        <tr class = 'rowClickable'>
            <td></td>
            <td><button type = 'submit' class = 'thumbnail_button' name = 'id_media' value = '1005'><img class = 'thumbnail' alt = 'Medium öffnen' src = 'thumb_placeholder.jpg'></button></td>
            <td>Präsentation</td>
            <td>fe wf we</td>
            <td>Hallo.pptx</td>
            <td>null</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

JQuery:

```
$("body").one("click", ".rowClickable", function() {
    console.log($(this).find("button").val());
    $(this).find("button").trigger("click");
});
```

Like this everything works fine. Just that I don't want to use .one("click").

Comment: try `on` with `e.preventDefault()`:- `$("body").on("click", ".rowClickable", function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
    console.log($(this).find("button").val());
    $(this).find("button").trigger("click");
});`

Comment: Stop the event's propagation when the `<button>` is clicked, for example: `$(".thumbnail_button").click(function(e){e.stopPropagation();})`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update your function to:**

```
$("body").on("click", ".rowClickable", function() {
    console.log($(this).find("button").val());
    $(this).find("button").click(function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
    }).trigger("click");
});
```

**UPDATED**:

```
$("body").on("click", ".rowClickable", function() {
    console.log($(this).find("button").val());
    $(this).find("button").trigger("click");
});

$('.rowClickable').find('button').click(function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

**UPDATED 1**:

```
$("body").on("click", ".rowClickable", function() {
    console.log($(this).find("button").val());
    $(this).find("button").off('click').click(function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
    }).trigger("click");
});
```

See [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sachinkk/y3xj5bcx/9/)

```js
$("body").on("click", ".rowClickable", function() {
    console.log($(this).find("button").val());
    $(this).find("button").trigger("click");
});

$('.rowClickable').find('button').click(function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method = 'post' action = 'view.cfm'>
    <table class = 'result_table'>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>Thumbnail</th>
            <th>Dateityp</th>
            <th>Titel</th>
            <th>Dateiname</th>
            <th>Dateigröße</th>
        </tr>
        <tr class = 'rowClickable'>
            <td></td>
            <td><button type = 'submit' class = 'thumbnail_button' name = 'id_media' value = '1005'><img class = 'thumbnail' alt = 'Medium öffnen' src = 'thumb_placeholder.jpg'></button></td>
            <td>Präsentation</td>
            <td>fe wf we</td>
            <td>Hallo.pptx</td>
            <td>null</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: handler inside handler is not a very good approach. it will attach new handler every-time which is time-consuming. register it one-time by putting it outside as i did in my answer

Comment: @AlivetoDie Thanks! got it :)

Comment: @JenSeReal  please take of my comments what i said

Comment: @AlivetoDie actually the non updated version is the only one i'm getting to work.. with all the other solutions im getting too much rekursion in the console

Comment: @JenSeReal, Answer updated with one more solution. Use `.off('click')`.

Answer (score 0):

As it is explained [here](http://api.jquery.com/one/)

```
$("body").on("click", ".rowClickable", function(event) {
    console.log($(this).find("button").val());
    $(this).find("button").trigger("click");
    $( this ).off( event );

});
```

You could use the off, to apply the same effect..